# MAMP PRO , Forbidden message , local server

Tags: mamp-pro

I can't see my local host on Mamp PRO, it was working in the free version - and still works in the free version -  but  I bought it because I thought it would be easier  to test in mobile devices and to have diverse projects running.
But  still every time  I run the browser it came with a "Forbidden message I don't have permission to access / on this server."

- I stopped sharing my internet in the  MAC OS X preferences  - as some  people here around suggested -
- I  have created new local server mounted in  Mamp pro. Same message

I don't have any idea or clue how to fix this.  It seems it is a permission issue at the local server level.  But I don't know

Thanks in advance for your help :D

Cheers 
V

Comment: So MAMP Pro is just a program that helps to configure your MAMP server, it doesn't run it's own standalone server so I think that's part of the reason why your question got buried. If you open MAMP Pro, go to the hosts tab, then, under the general tab, click Open, what do you see? Still the same error?

Comment: Thanks  for  your answer . 
 I just did a back up  and install everything again .   and yes I thing the previous configuration of  MAMP free version was causing troubles  with the  MAMP PRO.